# Bound on integral implies bound on function

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to prove this example.

Let $y(t):\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonincreasing function. Assume that there is a constant $A>0$ such that
\begin{equation} \int_{s}^{+\infty}y(t)dt \leq Ay(s), \quad 0\leq s<+\infty \end{equation}
Then $y(t)\leq y(0)e^{1-\frac{t}{A}}$, for all $t>0$.